# JavaScript naming conventions for conflicting classes

Tags: javascript, naming-conventions, naming

### TL;DR

How can we name classes having features that extend JavaScript's default classes functionality (e.g. `Array`).

### Explanation

I am the author of [AlgoFlux Runtime](https://github.com/AliFlux/AlgoFlux-Runtime/), a tiny library that provides classes for data-structures, algorithms and processing. This library has helper modules for `array`, `object`, `math`, `colors` and other cool stuff.

How should I name them? Right now I am using the following convention:

- `MathH`
- `ArrayH`
- `ObjectH`
- ..

Where `H` implies a Helper class. It looks kinda ugly right now.

#### Name-spacing?

Yeah, I could encapsulate all these like `AlgoFlux.Arrays.unique()`. But I want to keep it short, it would've been a good idea if JS supported `using <class>` statements, like in C#.

#### Prototyping?

Extending built-in classes is a bad idea. Making separate modules for this was a good design decision.

Any help regarding this issue would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Your question is rather on-topic to [CR](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) than SO. SO is for specific programming problems.

Comment: SO has 2,729 questions for `naming-conventions`. I guess this question qualifies as well.

Answer (score 0):

The question may be a bit opinion-based, but some options for you:

For now: Namespacing and/or AMD. Eventually: [ES6's modules](http://www.2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html).

**Namespacing:**

> Yeah, I could encapsulate all these like `AlgoFlux.Arrays.unique()`. But I want to keep it short...

Well, you don't need the plural (e.g. `AlgoFlux.Array.unique`). Let your users worry about short. For instance, if I want, then within my code after including your libary I can do this:

```
var A = AlgoFlux;
```

Then I use `A.Array.unique()`, which is only one character longer than `ArrayH.unique()`.

> ...it would've been a good idea if JS supported using  statements, like in C#.

The `var` statement above comes close; ES6 modules get all the way there.

**AMD**:

If you support AMD, then as with the namespacing above, your *user* gets to make this decision as appropriate to their code:

```
var A = require("AlgoFlux");
```

...or even:

```
var ArrayH = require("AlgoFlux.Array");
```

...if they so desire. :-)

**ES6 Modules:**

When you can start using them in the wild (as they're brand-new, broad support isn't there yet), it'll be:

```
import A from 'AlgoFlux';
```

or

```
import {Array as ArrayH} from 'AlgoFlux';
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd make it underscore-wise, so that you can have either

```
 your_namespace.method(someArray)
```

or

```
 your_namespace(someArray).method1().method2() etc
```

`AlgoFlux` is a bit too long for a namespace (and lowerCamelCase is more customary in javascript), therefore I'd go for something like

```
afx.array.getRandomValues(...)
```

[`d3`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/API-Reference) is a perfect example of such a multilevel namespace.